# How to create a manipulate window that plots two functions?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Original Function:

```
f[x_] := E^-2 x Cos[Pi x]
```

Manipulated Function:

```
Manipulate[Plot[E^-2 x Cos[Pi x] + c, {x, -3, 4}], {c, 0, 3}]
```

Is there a way to make these functions appear on the same window side-by-side? Have been trying various codes and commands, but nothing appears to work. I did get close one time, but I couldn't get a slider to appear.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_] := E^-2 x Cos[Pi x] 
colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"];
Manipulate[Row[Plot[#, {x, -3, 4}, PlotStyle -> #2, ImageSize -> 300, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{HoldForm@#}] , Above]] & @@@
   {{f[x], colors[[1]]}, {f[x] + c, colors[[2]]}}, Spacer[10]], {c, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

Add the option `PlotRange -> {-1, 4}` to  have a fixed vertical range on the second plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that plotting both functions on the same plot rather than side-by-side makes a better looking presentation.

```
f[x_] := E^-2 x Cos[Pi x]
g[f_, c_, rgb_?ColorQ] := Plot[f[x] + c, {x, -3, 4}, PlotStyle -> rgb]
Manipulate[
  Show[g[f, c, Black], g[f, 0, Red],
    PlotRange -> {-1.2, 3.3},
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
  {{c, 1}, -1, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]